# How can I make a multi panel on-screen keyboard? (XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas

We have an Intermec touchscreen terminal (OS: Win7).
We use an application on it that uses an on-screen keyboard stored in xaml files (VTFKey, VTKey, VTKeyCaps, VTKeyShifted, VTKeyShiftedCaps).

I pasted the code from VTKey.xaml for the buttons that toggle between keyboard panels (the xaml files mentioned above):

```html
<Button Canvas.Top="105.545" Height="49.995" Width="125" Command="{Binding Path=PressAndRelease}" CommandParameter="VK_CAPITAL" Content="Cap" />
<Button Canvas.Left="724" Canvas.Top="208.692" Height="50" Width="90" Command="{Binding Path=PressAndRelease}" CommandParameter="VK_TOGGLE" Content="Toggle" />
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ShiftKey}" Canvas.Left="836.583" Canvas.Top="156.651" Height="50" Width="163.317" Command="{Binding Path=PressAndHold}" CommandParameter="RSHIFT" Content="Shift" />
```

My question would be how do these commands (VK_CAPITAL, VK_TOGGLE, RSHIFT) know which xaml file to change to?
How could I create a custom keyboard consisting of 6 customized panels(xaml files)? Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *My question would be how do these commands (VK_CAPITAL, VK_TOGGLE, RSHIFT) know which xaml file to change to?*

You have XAML for the following three `Button`s:

```
<Button Canvas.Top="105.545" Height="49.995" Width="125"
    Command="{Binding Path=PressAndRelease}" CommandParameter="VK_CAPITAL" 
    Content="Cap" />
<Button Canvas.Left="724" Canvas.Top="208.692" Height="50" Width="90" 
    Command="{Binding Path=PressAndRelease}" CommandParameter="VK_TOGGLE" 
    Content="Toggle" />
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ShiftKey}" Height="50" Width="163.317" 
    Command="{Binding Path=PressAndHold}" CommandParameter="RSHIFT" 
    Content="Shift" />
```

Note the `Command` property... this is the name of the `ICommand` instance that performs the functionality for each `Button`. Two of these `Button`s use the `PressAndRelease Command`. In this case, the `CommandParameter` is also used... inside the `PressAndRelease Command` code, you would probably see something like this:

```
if (parameter == "VK_CAPITAL") LoadVkCapitalView();
...
else if (parameter == "VK_TOGGLE") LoadVkToggleView();
```

As for the last part of your question, you'll have ask a more precise question for me to be able to answer it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer sir! So you're saying unless I have access to the source code of the application (which I don't) I can't do much. Is this correct?

Comment: Not quite... if you have the XAML, then you can copy/paste that into a new WPF Application and then you'll just have to write the functionality part again, eg. the `ICommand`s.

Comment: Ah ok, well the application that uses these xaml-s is the ITE (Intermec Terminal Emulator (which comes with the terminal)), if I understand you correctly if we want to customize the keyboard we need to write our own "version" of ITE?

Comment: Yes unfortunately that's right, or at least the functionality part... unless you can get access to the source code.